# ArcMap topology toolbar validate topology button is disabled?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, topology, license

I find a strange thing when I try to use validate topology button. Most of the buttons on topology toolbar are disabled.

Last month when I was using a trial license of ArcGIS, I can use these functions.

From the instruction I find these functions only not available for the basic license. But I am using a standard license. Cannot figure out the reason.

The following pictures are the license information and the topology toolbar during editing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an ArcGIS for Desktop Standard or Advanced license level the only topology that you can create and modify is a Map Topology.  Geodatabase Topology is not available to the Basic level license.

Once you have [created a map topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01mm0000000r000000) or [created a geodatabase topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//006200000005000000), any of the buttons and tools that are available to you should no longer be grayed out.

It sounds like you may not have created either.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo, I created the topology in ArcCatalog and registered as versioned. Maybe I need to retry it.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, you are right. Now the topology toolbar works.